# How do I update an ActiveStorage blob in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activestorage

I have a file attached to a variable (@template) with the following blob:

```
#<ActiveStorage::Blob id: 581175, key: "0gm1oho37jwqlg4vdhhhabmhmbbs", filename: "open-uri20200122-24977-1gwql8e", content_type: "image/png", metadata: {"identified"=>true}, byte_size: 1651505, checksum: "U+Cj40eyRxQUBJWD1k6MBg==", created_at: "2020-01-22 17:45:49">
```

I need to update the metadata from `{"identified"=>true}` to `{"identified"=>true, "height"=> "300px", "width"=>"200px"}`

How do I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just execute

```
ActiveStorage::Blob.find(581175).update(metadata: {"identified"=>true, "height"=> "300px", "width"=>"200px"})
```

That's it.

Comment: So easy and obvious, don't know how I didn't think of that before.
Thanks, Mechnicov!

Comment: Yes, it's just `ActiveRecord` method. `ActiveStorage::Blob` is a model, its superclass is `ActiveRecord::Base`

Answer (score 0):

**I do not recommend that you do this**

But if is this that you want

```
your_object_with_active_storage = YourModel.find x
metadata = {"identified"=>true, "height"=> "300px", "width"=>"200px"}
blob_id = your_object_with_active_storage.attribute_attached.blob.id
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query %{
  UPDATE 
    "active_storage_blobs"
  SET
    "metadata" = '#{metadata.to_json}'
  WHERE
    "id" = #{blob_id}
}
```